# How to create asp.net Forum

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, forum

I just want to create an asp.net VB Forum and the database should be MS Access.

Comment: Anything else? Coffee? Tea?

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  So far all you're asking is, "I want to build something.  How do I do that?"

Comment: Why the requirement for a Jet/ACE back end? That seems like a really limiting starting choice if you intend any significant number of users. Jet/ACE can be OK for a web application back end if it's read-only and has a relatively small number of users, but a forum is going to require heavy-duty writes, and so I would suggest a more appropriate database engine.

Comment: First off, the question is amazingly broad.  Second, anybody using MS Access for a database for ANYTHING, especially a multithreaded multiuser environment such as ASP.NET, should be...  .... DAMN THIS DIAMOND.  I cannot tell you what should happen to them, but it should be generally unpleasant.

Answer (score 3):

No reason to be rude about this question. Here are some resources that can get you started.

http://www.asp.net/get-started is a good place for information about building your first ASP.NET application.

http://www.asp.net/community/projects#jm_starter_kits_and_samples has links to some starter kits that can get you up and running.

http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/the-beer-house is an older starter kit, for ASP.NET 2.0, but I used this a while back and it's pretty good.

As for using MS Access, I would try to get your first web application up and then ask a more specific question here on Stackoverflow when you run into some problems.